# Reasons about the difference between twisted affine algebras of $A_{2l}$ and other types

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, kac-moody-algebras

I am reading about Kac–Moody algebras. I have a question about the construction of twisted affine algebras.

Let $\sigma$ be a graph automorphism of the simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

When $\mathfrak{g}=(A_{2l},2)$, $(A_{2l-1},2)$, $(D_{l+1},2)$, $(E_{6},2)$ or $(D_4,3)$, the fixed point $\mathfrak{g}_0\subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ of $\sigma$ is also a simple algebra and has the type $B_l$, $C_l$, $B_l$, $F_4$ or $G_2$ respectively. $2,2,2,2,3$ mean the corresponding the oder of $\sigma$ as a automorphism.

But when $\mathfrak{g}=A_{2l}$, the simple roots of $\mathfrak{g}_0$ are indexed by $\{0,1,\dotsc ,l-1\}$.

When $\mathfrak{g}=A_{2l-1}$, $D_{l+1}$, $E_6$, $D_4$, the simple roots of $\mathfrak{g}_0$ are indexed by $\{1,\dotsc ,l\}$, $\{1, \dotsc, l\}$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{1,2\}$ respectively.

When constructing twisted affine algebras, we need to add an extra point. For $A_{2l}$, the extra point is indexed by $l$. For other types, the extra point is indexed by $0$.

I'm wondering what internal reason this is for such a difference between $A_{2l}$ and other types?

---

**New explanations of the problem**

It comes from Kac's "[Infinite dimensional Lie algebras](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511626234)" and a lecture from [Introduction to Kac–Moody Lie algebras](http://www.hcm.uni-bonn.de/homepages/prof-dr-nicolas-perrin/teaching/introduction-to-kac-moody-lie-algebras/) for twisted affine algebras.

As we know we have affine types $A^{(2)}_{2l}$, $A^{(2)}_{2l-1}$, $D^{(2)}_{l+1}$, $E^{(2)}_{6}$ and $D^{(4)}_{3}$, we want to construct the corresponding Kac–Moody algebra.

In Kac's book and the above lecture, we should firstly  use the graph automorphism to get the corresponding fixed-point subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}_0$.

> For example, when $\mathfrak{g}=A_{2l}$, the fixed-point subalgebra
> $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is the simple Lie algebra $B_l$ and we have the
> simple roots $\{\alpha_0,\dotsc, \alpha_{l-1}\}$, generators $e_i,
>  f_i$ ($0\le i\le l-1$) and Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}_0$.
>
> When $\mathfrak{g}=A_{2l-1}$, the fixed-point subalgebra
> $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is the simple Lie algebra $C_l$ and we have the
> simple roots $\{\alpha_1,\dotsc, \alpha_{l}\}$ and $e_i, f_i$ ($1\le i\le
> l$) and Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}_0$.

Let $\hat{\mathcal{L}}\left( \mathfrak{g} \right) =\left( \mathbb{C} \left[ t,t^{-1} \right] \otimes \mathfrak{g} \right) \oplus \mathbb{C} c\oplus \mathbb{C} d$ with Lie bracket $$\left[ t^a\otimes x+\lambda c+\mu d,t^b\otimes y+\lambda ^{\prime}c+\mu \prime d \right] =\left[ x,y \right] \otimes t^{a+b}+\mu y\otimes bt^b-\mu ^{\prime}x\otimes at^a+a\delta _{a,-b}\left( x,y \right) c.$$

When constructing the $A^{(2)}_{2l}$ and  $A^{(2)}_{2l-1}$, $D^{(2)}_{l+1}$, $E^{(2)}_{6}$, $D^{(3)}_{4}$ in Kac's book and the above lectures, they put $A^{(2)}_{2l}$ in one case and put $A^{(2)}_{2l-1}$, $D^{(2)}_{l+1}$, $E^{(2)}_{6}$ and $D^{(3)}_{4}$ in the other case.

> We consider the fixed points of $\hat{\mathcal{L}}\left( \mathfrak{g}
> \right) $ under the extended automorphism $\sigma$ by the formula
> $\sigma \left( t^a\otimes x+\lambda c+\mu d \right) =\frac{1}{\xi
>  ^a}t^a\otimes \sigma \left( x \right) +\lambda c+\mu d$ where $\xi
> =e^{\frac{i2\pi}{m}}$ and $m$ is the order of $\sigma$.
>
> For example, when $\mathfrak{g}=A_{2l-1}$, we can put $E_i=1\otimes
> e_i$ and $f_i=1\otimes f_i(1\le i\le l)$ and $E_0=t\otimes e_0$,
> $F_0=t^{-1}\otimes f_0$ where $e_0\in E_{\theta}$ and $f_0 \in
> > E_{{-\theta}}$ ($\theta$ is the highest root of $C_l$).
>
> When $\mathfrak{g}=A_{2l}$, we can put $E_i=1\otimes e_i$ and
> $f_i=1\otimes f_i(0\le i\le l-1)$ and $E_l=t\otimes e_l$,
> $F_l=t^{-1}\otimes f_l$ where $e_l\in E_{\theta}$ and $f_l\in
> > E_{{-\theta}}$ ($\theta$ is the highest root of $B_l$).

If we simply look at the Dynkin diagram, we have the picture for $A^{(2)}_{2l-1}$:[image: pic 1]

For $A^{(2)}_{2l}$, we have [image: pic 2]

Now I wonder why there exist such a difference in the construction  and the order of labelling between $A^{(2)}_{2l}$ and $A^{(2)}_{2l-1}$, $D^{(2)}_{l+1}$, $E^{(2)}_{6}$, $D^{(3)}_{4}$ ?

> I think it's just a matter of numerical order, and we can renumber it
> to make $A^{(2)}_{2l}$ and $A^{(2)}_{2l-1}$, $D^{(2)}_{l+1}$,
> $E^{(2)}_{6}$, $D^{(3)}_{4}$  coincide. Is it true?

Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this question, but I'm not sure that I understand it.  The numbering of the roots in a root system is arbitrary.  If I were numbering the roots of $A_{2l}$ as $\{1, \dotsc, 2l\}$, then I would number the roots of the fixed-point subalgebra $B_l$ as $\{1, \dotsc, l\}$, where $l$ is the short simple root.  Are you seeing a source that does it differently?

Comment: @LSpice I have add some details. It comes from Kac's book and the lectures when I read about the construction of twisted affine algebras.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459872/reasons-about-the-difference-between-twisted-affine-algebras-of-a-2l-and-oth#comment1192007_459872), certainly there are strange things about $A_{2l}^{(2)}$ (it's the only case where an orbit of roots can fail to be strongly orthogonal) that often require it to be treated differently, but I think that this particular thing is, indeed, just a choice of numbering.  But it'd be hard to say without seeing what effect it has later in the book/lecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra with Dynkin diagram of type $X$. Let $\sigma$ be a diagram automorphism of $X$ of order $k$. Then the affine Dynkin diagram of type $X^{(k)}$ has a "distinguished node" so that after deleting it we are left with the Dynkin diagram of the fixed point subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}_0$. (This characterizes the node up to diagram automorphism.)

The labeling of the simple roots for affine Lie algebras used by Kac is the unique one so that $\alpha_0$ is the distinguished node of the Langlands dual Dynkin diagram. In other words, after reversing all the arrows in the affine Dynkin diagram, $\alpha_0$ labels the distinguished node of the resulting diagram.

It's worth noting that Kac's convention was already in the literature when *Infinite Dimensional Lie Algebras* was written. An earlier reference using it is

*Kac, Victor G.; Peterson, Dale H.*, [**Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras, theta functions and modular forms**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(84)90032-X), Adv. Math. 53, 125-264 (1984). [ZBL0584.17007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0584.17007).

Here seems to be the main benefit of Kac's convention: both the article and the book use the fact that the primitive imaginary root $\delta$ differs from the highest root of the finite root system spanned by $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_l$ by a multiple of $\alpha_0$. This is true with Kac's labeling but not with an "$\alpha_0=$ distinguished node" labeling. However, as you noticed, Kac's labeling complicates the usual construction of a twisted affine Lie algebra via an automorphism. Ultimately, the choice is yours to make.

**Edit:** Here is an example indicating the difference between the distinguished node and the one that Kac labels $\alpha_0$. The distinguished node in every diagram is indicated in red. The left and right sides are related by Langlands duality. Starting from a diagram on the left, to determine which node Kac would label $\alpha_0$, we look at which node is distinguished in the diagram on the right. The corresponding node on the left is $\alpha_0$.
[image: Examples of distinguished nodes]

Comment: As you say in the second paragraph, in $A^{(2)}_{2l}$, $\alpha_0$ is the distinguished point not the added point $\alpha_l$. But for other types, the add point $\alpha_l$ is the distinguished point?  Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @fusheng Given a diagram with Kac's labeling, the distinguished point is the one named $\alpha_0$ in every type except $A_{2l}^{(2)}$, where it is the one named $\alpha_l$. You can see this last fact since $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is type $B_l$, and the only node we can delete from $A_{2l}^{(2)}$ to get a $B_l$ diagram is $\alpha_l$.

Comment: @ Grant B Thanks! I can get it. But if I inverse the number of $A^{(2)}_{2l}$ with Kac's labeling, then delete $\alpha_0$, we can also get the type $B_l$. That is why I am confused

Comment: @fusheng In the images from your post, the distinguished nodes are the ones colored red. This is completely unrelated to the labels in the image. You can number the nodes however or leave them unlabeled and the distinguished node is still the one you have colored red. So it makes sense to talk about distinguished nodes before we pick a labeling.

Comment: @ Grant B Thanks! Maybe I know it.  Is it  that $A^{(2)}_{2l}$, $A^{(2)}_{2l-1}$, $D^{(2)}_{l+1}$, $E^{(2)}_{6}$ and $D^{(4)}_{3}$ can be constructed in the same case while Kac complicates the construction ? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @fusheng The labeling doesn't affect the construction, only the way it is described in writing. Yes, where the exposition uses $\epsilon$ to denote either $0$ or $l$, it would be simpler to use a $0$. But if you make this change, you have to be careful in other parts, such as the construction of the imaginary root $\delta$, where the exposition assumes $\alpha_0$ is the (not necessarily distinguished) node indicated by Kac.

Comment: @ Grant B  Thank you very much! I get it.

Comment: @fusheng, if this answers your question satisfactorily (as your accepting it seems to indicate), then don't forget also to award the bounty.